# Set secondary colors in Material Design Theme in Flutter

Tags: flutter, material-design, theming

Where do I set the seconday colors from https://material.io/resources/color/ ?

According to the `ThemeData` class I have to set the `accentColor`, which I know how to do: "The [accentColor], sometimes called the secondary color".

After analyzing `theme_data.dart` you can also set the `colorScheme.secondary`. But setting a property of `ColorScheme` means that you have to set all properties. Are you even supposed to set `ColorScheme` and override it? Also where do I set Secondary Light and Secondary Dark colors? I feel kinda lost as the only way to customize the `ThemeData` is reading the whole material theming code. Or at least large parts of it. Is there any in depth documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where do I set the seconday colors from https://material.io/resources/color/ ?

In general, a good place to do that is in `ThemeData` which can be passed as a [`theme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/theme.html) argument to `MaterialApp`.

> But setting a property of `ColorScheme` means that you have to set all properties

Not necessarily - unless I misinterpret the question. `ColorScheme` has a method [`copyWith()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme/copyWith.html) which takes a bunch of named arguments. Therefore, you can reuse existing `ColorScheme` like so:

```
final newScehme = someColorScheme.copyWith(background: ...)
```

Of course, the trick is to retrieve that scheme. You can probably get away with retrieving it by accessing `ThemeData's` [`colorScheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/colorScheme.html) property:

```
Theme.of(context).colorScheme
```

> Are you even supposed to set `ColorScheme` and override it?

I have not seen anything in the documentation that would advise against this, although I did not comb through all of it. I suppose it depends on your use case.

> Also where do I set Secondary Light and Secondary Dark colors?

I am not particularly well-versed in Material design guidelines and intricacies, but perhaps [`secondary`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme/secondary.html) and [`secondaryVariant`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme/secondaryVariant.html) are what you're after?

> Is there any in depth documentation?

Depends on your definition of in-depth. The following links provide a reasonable overview of various properties related to theming & colors:

- [`Theme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html)
- [`ThemeData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html)
- [`ColorScheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html)

Also note that there is a [`darkTheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/darkTheme.html) property on `MaterialApp` which you can use to specify dark theme when it is requested by the system.

In general, I find that `ThemeData` has a plethora of customisation options, especially when you combine it with `copyWith` that's present on many theme-related classes. Whether `ThemeData` closely matches Material design guidelines I cannot say with any confidence. However, documentation does explain properties rather well, so comparing them to actual guidelines should give one an idea of what's what.

Comment: `colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: Colors.amber)` is working just fine. I already thought about that but didn't try. Thanks for the hint. I guess I'll have to do lots of trial and error to find which color is mapped to which widget. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want the `copyWith` method, which allows you to override as little or as much of a parent ThemeData.